# Setting Modules in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an AngulrJS module that I intend to share, for free, with other developers via GitHub/bower. While my approach currently works, I'm concerned about name collisions. The way that I am currently setting up my module is like this:

```
var myModuleName = angular.module('myModuleName', []);
myModuleName.factory('$myFirstServiceName', function() {
 ...
});

myModuleName.factory('$mySecondServiceName', ['$q', function($q) {
 ...
}]);

myModuleName.factory('$myThirdServiceName', ['$q', function($q) {
 ...
}]);
```

My concern is that global 'myModuleName'. While this approach works, the name of my module isn't that "special". For that reason, I'm concerned it will collide with a developers existing stuff or cause other problems down the road.

Is there any way to more elegantly create a module where I don't have to worry about naming collisions?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just name the module something special? I'm pretty sure that the only way that you are going to avoid naming collisions is to have a unique name.

Comment: I'm open to that. I was asking more for the purpose of education. I was wondering if I was doing something incorrectly or not.

Comment: Interesting question. I think for the actual name of the module you'll have to be unique. For the var myModuleName: I think minification is the way that would normally prevent this.

Comment: I wouldn't think too much about a unique name. Name the module with a name that describes the functionality what it actually does. Chances are, that developers only pick one module for one job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use prefix in module name, which present project/library/author.

Like `pasvaz.bindonce`, `ui.router` etc...